# VBA Powerpoint - Modify category names

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint, axis, categories

I'm trying to modify category names of an existing chart in VBA powerpoint with the below code, but instead the category names are removed from the chart.

```
Dim mCatArray() As String
lngSeries = 0
Dim testvar As Variant

'Get the existing category names in an Array
'oSh = Shape element
For Each testvar In oSh.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames
    strIn = ProperCaps(testvar & "", objRegex)
    ReDim Preserve mCatArray(lngSeries)

    'Do my changes and insert the category name in the Array
    mCatArray(lngSeries) = strIn

    lngSeries = lngSeries + 1
Next

'Assign the Changed Category array back - METHOD 1
For lngSeries = 1 To .Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
   oSh.Chart.SeriesCollection(lngSeries).XValues = mCatArray
Next

'Assign the Changed Category array back - METHOD 2
   oSh.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = mCatArray
```

Both the method's don't seem to help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  What are you trying to change the categories from and to, and why can't you change them in the chart's source data? Also you should declare your variables, an only include the relevant code in your question (see "*[mcve]*".)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to change the category names to a proper case sentence. Anyways. I'm able to retrieve the category names in to a string array and change them, but i'm struggling to assign them back to the category axis. So the last line( oSh.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = mCatArray) doesn't seem to work. It seems to remove the category all together. mCatArray is the array retrieved earlier. hope that makes it clear. Thanks